# Travel around the city in 10 steps

Tags: javascript

We travel around the city in 4 cardinal directions and can only take 10 steps and must return to the place where we started. My program breaks on tests (didn't come to the place where I started from). Where is the mistake? I know that it can be solved easier, but I would like to know what my mistake is

```
function isValidWalk(walk) {
    let x = 0, y = 0;
    let result = 0;
    if(walk.length !== 10) {
        return false;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(walk[i] === 'n') {
            x += 1;
        }
        else if(walk[i] === 's') {
            x += -1
        }
        else if(walk[i] === 'w') {
            y += -1;
        }
        else if(walk[i] === 'e') {
            y += 1;
        }
    }
    result = x + y;

    if(result === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What's the input? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks on tests"?

Comment: @ggorlen, the input is probably an array like this: `var walk = ['n', 'n', 's', 's', 'n', 'n', 's', 's', 'n', 's' ];`

Comment: @GeekyQuentin It probably is, but it's be nice if OP shared the failing test and a clear problem statement rather than expecting us to guess. There's too much ambiguity here.

Comment: @ggorlen, I think the logic is incorrect because `x` can be `1` and `y` can be `-1`. Hence we have to check if both `x` and `y` are `0`

Comment: You're right, the answer got it. But OP should still be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You need ot check `x` and `y` directly. Their values should be zero, because you can not go north and west to get a neutral position.

```
if (x === 0 && y === 0) return true;
return false;
```

For example look to this walk

```
NWSSEN
```

There you have a balanced north and south, as well west and east.

Comment: Thank you! But unless we check x and y on a straight line, something should change? If x = 0 and y =0, then result = x + y = 0, why doesn't it work like that?

Comment: you can not just add horizontal movements and verival movements. you need to compare each movement.